# MyBatis - lists of primitive types

Tags: mybatis

This seems to have eluded me. I know I can use a map to return a vanilla set of rows from a myBatis query but how to do it with a **list** of primitive types?

e.g. If I had SQL like:

```
select product_price from products
```

Does this require a resultMap? I've tried to use java.util.ArrayList as the result type but get class not found errors.

In a similar vein, how do I pass a list of items as an argument to a query.

Any input, pointers to docs appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just declare the `resultType` as the primitive type that you want, which in your case is a `Long`. It will be returned as a list.

```
<select id="getPrice" resultType="java.lang.Long">
  select product_price from products
</select>
```

In the mapper interface you should expect to get back a list of `Long`.

```
List<Long> getPrice();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using below code snippet inside your resultmap for product_price column mapping -

```
  <collection property="price" ofType="java.lang.Long">
              <result property="price" column="product_price"/> 
  </collection>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using resultMap

```
<resultMap type="java.lang.Long" id="domainsResult"> 
     <result property="" column="product_price"/> 
</resultMap>

<select id="getPrice" resultMap="domainsResult">
   select product_price from products
</select>
```

It will give you a List priceList.

Comment: I use the empty property tricks in my <collection> elements in resultmap, and it solves my problem (different from the post). Thanks so much!

Comment: please mark any suitable answer as accepted and close this question. It will help other people too with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trey this :

You will get it as a list of map if you write like this:

```
<select id="getPrice" resultType="Hashmap">
   select product_price from products
</select>
```

Where the key will be column name. Each map will contain a single entry. If You want an ArrayList then you can write a function to convert this map to an ArrayList:

```
public List listFromListOfMap (List<Map> listOfMap ) {

  List<Integer> prices = new ArrayLisyt<Integer>();
  for(int i = 0; i < listOfMap.size(); i++) {

      Integer value = (Integer)listOfMap.get(i).get("product_price");
      prices.add(value);
  }
  return prices;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that if you simply set the resultType to the Class def, it gives a list of those objects (if you have custom classes). I'm wondering for primitive types if I just set resultType to java.lang.Integer it'll work out. I'll have to try it. Thanks for the code above.