# How to map an int[] to an integer[] in postgres using mybatis

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I have an integer array int[] sizes in my java pojo. And I'm storing it in postgres as sizes integer[] . I'm trying to map it using mybatis using a result map like:

```
<resultMap id="result" type="javaPojo">
   <result column="sizes" jdbcType="ARRAY" property="sizes"/>
</resultMap>
```

Every time I'm getting an error like :

> Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration, Cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property sizes.

Everything is generated procedurally using java which I cannot disclose because of company policies.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error because **typeHandlers** didn't support int[]. For more detail support type of mybatis you can refer: [Type Handlers Mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).

Now I have 2 solutions for you.

1. Create new Type Handler [here](https://www.javatips.net/api/mybatis-java-time-master/mybatis-types-master/src/main/java/com/github/javaplugs/mybatis/ArrayTypeHandler.java#).
2. Changing `int[]` to `List<Integer>`.

Example code:

Just declare the resultType as the primitive type that you want, which in your case is a Integer. It will be returned as a list.

```
<select id="getPrice" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
  select product_price from products
</select>
```

In the mapper interface you should expect to get back a list of Long.

```
List<Integer> getPrice();
```

I clone example above from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179890/mybatis-lists-of-primitive-types)

Comment: If it is changed to list what should be the structure of the resultMap. I am very new to mybatis.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis has a built-in `ArrayTypeHandler`, however, it may return `Integer[]` not `int[]` (it depends on the driver's `ResultSet#getArray()` implementation).

If you can change the property type to `Integer[]`, there are two ways to use the built-in `ArrayTypeHandler`.

1. Local setting: specify `typeHandler` explicitly in `<result />`.

   ```xml
   <result column="sizes" jdbcType="ARRAY" property="sizes" 
     typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler" />
   ```
2. Global setting: register `ArrayTypeHandler` against `int[]` in MyBatis config. With XML config, it would look as follows.

   ```xml
   <typeHandlers>
     <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler"
       javaType="int[]" jdbcType="ARRAY" />
   </typeHandlers>
   ```

---

If the property type has to be `int[]` for some reason, you may have to write a custom type handler that converts `Integer[]` into `int[]`.
Assuming that you are using MyBatis 3.5.0 or later, you can subclass the built-in implementation and override `extractArray()` method.

```java
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler;

public class IntArrayTypeHandler extends ArrayTypeHandler {
  @Override
  protected Object extractArray(Array array) throws SQLException {
    Integer[] src = (Integer[]) super.extractArray(array);
    int[] dest = new int[src.length];
    // Assuming there is no null in the data
    Arrays.setAll(dest, i -> src[i]);
    return dest;
  }
}
```

Usage is mostly the same as the built-in one.
When specifying `javaType` in XML config, however, `javaType` must be `_int[]` because `int` is an [alias](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeAliases) for `Integer`.